# Control order of GeoJSON layers

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, layer-control

I'm trying to fix the order of appereance of my GeoJSON layers. Precisely, I have a layer of circle markers that I want always to be over polygon layers. At the moment, when a polygon layer is checked in the controller after the circle markers layer, it appears above... Does someone have an idea ?

Here is my layers control :

```
L.control.layers(baselayers, data, {position: 'topright', collapsed: true}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: For solution see https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

Comment: This is not enough of relevant code, layers definitions are missing.